# Enable Google Map Directions when URL has parameters

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have settled a Google Map Dealer Locator which displays dealers throughout the world. When you click on a dealer's pinpoint, you get an infobox in which there's a link that opens a panel to calculate directions between some departure location (the user has to fill it) and the dealer.

This is working well.

My issue is, I had to make this locator translatable and customizable (center on a specific country for instance), so I chose to do this by passing paramaters in the URL (i.e.: to get the german version centered on Germany, the URL would be something like mylocator.com/?lang=de&country=germany).

Now when I use the Locator with parameters like these and I try to get directions to a dealer, there is some kind of bug that make the web page refresh to a URL without parameters (like mylocator.com/#). And I get no directions...

Do you have any clue on what could cause this ?

Here is some code I use :

HTML :

```
<body onload="load()">
    <section class="navbar">
        some code to display a form for dealer's selection and display
    </section>
    <section id="directions-panel">
        <div id="routecontent">
            <div>
                <form onsubmit="calcRoute();">
                    <input type="text" id="start">
                    <input type="text" id="end">
                    <button type="submit"></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="mypanel"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="map"></section>
```

JS :

```
function load() {
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var myOptions = {
        center: centrage,
        zoom: zooming,
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("mypanel"));
}
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
             directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Based on the description of your problem I don't think there's enough information here yet. For example, that url sounds like what you'd get if a link with nothing but a "#" for the href value were clicked. Can you expand on what happens when you have this issue?

Comment: the "#" comes from the jQuery function I wrote to display the direction panel when you click on the link in the infobox. By default, this panel is hidden. So, first the URL is mylocator.com/?lang=de&country=germany, then when click on the link in the infobox is turns to mylocator.com/?lang=de&country=germany#, then filling in the form in the direction panel and submiting it, then the page refresh on URL mylocator.com/?#. And when I use the locator with no parameters behind the URL (default display), I have no errors, the directions are displayed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a preventDefault() call on the event passed to your submit handler:

```
 function calcRoute(ev) {

     // var declarations

     ev.preventDefault();

     // other stuff that's getting directions
}
```

Because it's a form, it wants to submit the form when you click that submit button. Since you're handling the processing of the form client-side, prevent the default action using preventDefault.

Comment: Great, I'll try this and get back to you. I didn't think about this, and it looks like a possible cause.

Comment: Perfect, it worked like a charm ! I changed my calcRoute() function to : $("#myform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Google Maps API, surely it uses the browsers default language settings in order to localise it without and need for input from you. Unless you're not using the Maps API, in which case, this comment is useless.

Comment: I'm using the API, but the translation is also form all the HTML around the map (panels, forms, infobox details...). So I'm the one dealing with it.